# const string plus boolean to pluralize in C

Tags: c, string, boolean, plural

I'm surprised string plus boolean has similar effect of ternary operation:

```
int apple = 2;                                                                      
printf("apple%s\n", "s" + (apple <= 1));
```

If `apple <= 1`, it will print apple. Why does this work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the condition evaluates to either 0 or 1, and the string `"s"` contains exactly one character before the 0-terminator. So `"s" + bool` will evaluate to the address of `"s"` if `bool` is false, and to one character behind that, the address of the 0-terminator if true.

It's a cool hack, but don't ever use code like that in earnest.